# How to prevent redundant spaces and commas in a Pandas dataframe when saving to file using Pickle in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

**how to remove unnecessary spaces and commas from a pandas dataframe**
**i am unable to show the appended dataframe properly withouth unnecessary spaces and commas,**

here is my code the saving works perfectly by not overwriting the file but instead appending to it which I required but while displaying the appended data from the file unnecessary spaces and commas appear which I do not want.

This is the dataframe which is updated in the interface if and when a user changes or appends to it.

```
data_frame = {" Expenses " : [],
              " Amount " : [],
              " Date " : []}
db = pd.DataFrame(data_frame)
```

This is my save function which saves the data to a file by appending to it, if the file does not contain any data the function appends the dataframe [db] without removing the column names whereas if
the file does contain data the function removes the column names of the new dataframe [db] and then appends to the file to avoid overlapping column names....

```
def Save():
    if os.path.getsize("MoneyData.dat") == 0:    ##this line checks if the data file contains data or not.
        existing_data = [] 
    else:
        db.columns = [''] * len(db.columns) ## this removes column names to avoid overlapping column names
        try:
    # Open the file in binary read mode
            with open('MoneyData.dat', 'rb') as file:
        # Load the existing data
                 existing_data = pickle.load(file)
        except FileNotFoundError:
             existing_data = []
    
    
    existing_data.append(db)


    with open('MoneyData.dat', 'wb') as file:

        pickle.dump(str(existing_data), file, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

this is my load function which loads the updated file and prints the data :

```
def load():
    global Showdata     ## These global variables do not have significance to the code execution
    global Stop_butto
    Saved_Data = pickle.load(open("MoneyData.dat", "rb"))
    print(Saved_Data)
```

this code results in correct saving but while printing or displaying the final data, it contains unnecessary indents or spaces as seen here :

[**Click This Image..**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6Z79.png)

I am using Tkinter button to display the contents but regardless the problem occurs in terminal print also.

Comment: I'm not sure I understain exactly what you want, but you can use the strip function to remove extra whitespaces and remove commas using replace, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html

Comment: Thanks so much it worked perfectly, I just wanted the extra spaces to be removed, I didn't know that such a function existed.